# SQL Group by query with case statement issue

Tags: sql

I have below query:

```
   SELECT
        fact_order_payment.paymenttype  AS "paymenttype",
        COUNT(DISTINCT fact_order_payment.orderpaymentkey ) AS "count"
    FROM  Fact_order_payment  AS fact_order_payment
    INNER JOIN  Fact_order  AS fact_order ON fact_order.orderkey = fact_order_payment.orderkey
    WHERE (fact_order_payment.paymenttype='CreditCard'
    GROUP BY 1
```

Result:

```
PaymentType             Count
CreditCard              7497
```

But, when I add addition column in select, then my result get change (check count).

```
SELECT
        fact_order_payment.paymenttype  AS "paymenttype",
        COUNT(DISTINCT fact_order_payment.orderpaymentkey ) AS "count",
    NULLIF((COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN CASE when fact_order.status not in ('Submitted', 'PendingReview', 'Pending', 'Abandoned', 'Cancelled', 'Canceled', 'Errored') then true else false END  THEN fact_order.orderkey ELSE NULL END)),0)  AS "count2"
    FROM  Fact_order_payment  AS fact_order_payment
    INNER JOIN  Fact_order  AS fact_order ON fact_order.orderkey = fact_order_payment.orderkey
    WHERE (fact_order_payment.paymenttype='CreditCard'
    GROUP BY 1
```

Result:

```
PaymentType             Count       count2
CreditCard              7297         9870
```

Is that because of "Case statement" in third column? Not sure. Suggestion needed.

Comment: Is this a consistent result after running queries multiple times?

Comment: @user2493287 . . . What you are describing should not be happening in any database.  My guess is a transcription mistake when you run the first query or the underlying data changes.  A new column in the `SELECT` should not be changing the number or content of the rows being processed.

Comment: @AlexLarionov yes

Comment: @GordonLinoff - This is dev data, which change once a day. When I remove "Case statement" from second query, I do get expected result.